# Reasoning on Efficiency

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, computability

It is possible to *prove* the correctness of algorithms, and two algorithms can be compared to see which has better performance using $O$ and $o$ notation.

Is it possible to *prove* the efficiency of an algorithm? I.e. That that algorithm is the most efficient *possible* algorithm for a problem.

Let $K_i$ be the set of all algorithms(both known and unknown) for solving a particular problem $P_i$ 
$$K_i = [A_{i1}, A_{i2}, ... ,A_{in}]$$

Is it possible that given an Algorithm $A_{ij}$, one can prove that
$$\forall A_{ix} \in K_i, A_{ij} = o(A_{ix})$$

If the answer is yes, is there a known method to do this?

Comment: How is this different from your [follow-up question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67099/reasoning-on-efficiency-3)?

Comment: You must specify the model of computation for this.